# pyo3 compiles & imports correctly but exits without any error message when a function is run

Tags: python, rust, pyo3

As soon as my python module calls a rust function, it exits without any output and ignores try/except blocks. My code is something like this:

python:

```py
def call_rust(some_bytes: bytes):
    print("debug")
    val = rust_function(some_bytes)
    print("yes")
    return val
```

rust:

```rs
#[pyfunction]
fn rust_function(bytes: &[u8]) -> PyResult<...> {
    println!("more testing");
    // --actual code--
}
```

This ends up only printing "debug".

The rust function is in another module which is then registered in lib.rs with:

```rs
// --imports--
mod other_module;

#[pymodule]
fn mainmod(_py: Python, m: &PyModule) -> PyResult<()> {
    m.add_function(wrap_pyfunction!(other_module::rust_function, m)?)?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Compiling doesn't give errors, and importing it works fine.

Is there a way to debug this?

Edit: It had something to do with the code itself and not with the library. I overused the stack with a large array and replacing it with a vector worked (see comments).

Comment: The example you provided does not compile. If it is compiling without issue for you, then perhaps you are compiling incorrectly. Rust code using pyo3 still must be defined in rust syntax, and the example you gave is a weird combination of python and rust.

Comment: How are you compiling your library?

Comment: My bad, I corrected the example. I'm compiling with `maturin develop`.

Comment: Is your rust function public? Are you importing the function, or just the package (`from pkg import rust_function` vs `import pkg`)? What error does the interpreter exit with when it fails?

Comment: Yes it's public, from outside the module I tried importing the specific function and the whole module with the same result, from within the module I imported with `from .pkg import rust_function`, and the interpreter prints absolutely nothing after the rust function is called.

Comment: It sounds like there may be code within `rust_function` that is problematic. Does the issue persist if you change `rust_function` to be just the println and nothing else? Maybe add the code of the `rust_function` to the question? I have compiled and successfully run your example as it appears above.

Comment: After some debugging, it seems to be this line of code is where everything stops:
`let mut fft_outputs = [[0.0; 1025]; 256];` however running it elsewhere returns the desired output. But I tried using a vector and it somehow worked. So thanks cuz it is an issue with the code itself.

Comment: ahh, it’s likely you have a large amount of data on the stack, and that put you over the limit. On linux, the default max stack size is 8mb, and that 2mb array could put you over if you have a huge stack already. Vectors are allocated on the heap and therefore not subject to this limitation

Comment: Oh I didn't know, thanks, it makes more sense now